# A weird error of undefined function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, undefined, radix, derived

I defined a base and derived class, both defined a function called "getYear":

```
function Base() {}
Base.prototype.getYear = function() {
    return 2015;
}

function Derived() {
    year = 2016;
}
Derived.prototype = new Base();
Derived.prototype.getYear = function() {
    return 2017;
}

var ins = new Derived();
console.log(ins.getYear());
console.log(ins.prototype.getYear());
```

The last statement will trigger a runtime error saying

```
 Cannot read property 'getYear' of undefined
```

Would you help to explain the reason?
I think I have defined this function in both base/derived function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prototypes` (instance methods) are declared on the `Constructor`, and only used on the `instance`. If you wanted to use the original prototype method based on the instance, you could do something like:

```
var ins = new Derived();
ins.constructor.prototype.getYear();
```

where you get the `getYear` prototype from the original `constructor`. However, this kind of defeats the purpose of using the prototypes in the instance sense.

Here is your example, reworked to do what you were trying to:

```js
function Base() {}
Base.prototype.getYear = function() {
  return 2015;
}

function Derived() {
  year = 2016;
}
Derived.prototype = new Base();
Derived.prototype.getYear = function() {
  return 2017;
}

var ins = new Derived();
console.log(ins.getYear());
console.log(ins.constructor.prototype.getYear());
```